# uC/OS-II Will OS_EXIT_CRITICAL() execute in the OS_Sched()?

Tags: ucos

In the OS_Sched(), a context switch will perform after OS_TASK_SW(), processor will execute a higher priority task.
But when will the OS_EXIT_CRITICAL() be executed?

```
void  OS_Sched (void)
{
#if OS_CRITICAL_METHOD == 3u                           /* Allocate storage for CPU status register     */
    OS_CPU_SR  cpu_sr = 0u;
#endif



    OS_ENTER_CRITICAL();
    if (OSIntNesting == 0u) {                          /* Schedule only if all ISRs done and ...       */
        if (OSLockNesting == 0u) {                     /* ... scheduler is not locked                  */
            OS_SchedNew();
            OSTCBHighRdy = OSTCBPrioTbl[OSPrioHighRdy];
            if (OSPrioHighRdy != OSPrioCur) {          /* No Ctx Sw if current task is highest rdy     */
#if OS_TASK_PROFILE_EN > 0u
                OSTCBHighRdy->OSTCBCtxSwCtr++;         /* Inc. # of context switches to this task      */
#endif
                OSCtxSwCtr++;                          /* Increment context switch counter             */
                OS_TASK_SW();                          /* Perform a context switch                     */
            }
        }
    }
    OS_EXIT_CRITICAL();
}
```